# How can I fix my org-loaddefs.el?

Tags: org-mode

I went to start emacs today and was greeted with this:

```
WARNING: No org-loaddefs.el file could be found from where org.el is loaded.
```

followed by

```
You need to run "make" or "make autoloads" from Org lisp directory
```

Any idea how I can fix this error?

Comment: It says you should generate autoload file. After setup load-path, you also need to load `org-loaddefs.el` via `(require 'org-loaddefs)` (BTW, there is no need to load any other features). Please follow http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html to install org from git.

Comment: Did running "make" or "make autoloads" from Org lisp directory make the problem go away, or not?

Answer (score 3):

As hinted at by [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-11/msg00131.html) the issue can arise when the org installation is newer than the Emacs version which is running.

A simple solution is remove the org package. If it is marked as "builtin" in the package-list-packages view, remove the entire

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20xxxxxx`
```

directory instead.